# React Native app - how to use oauth 2.0 and Open ID connect?

Tags: oauth-2.0, react-native, redux, openid-connect, redux-saga

I've searched and spent so much time wrapping my head around this. Given a **client_id**, **client_secret**, **authorization_endpoint**, **auth URL**, **token_endpoint** and a few other info--

*

1. How do I do connect to get an auth token via ajax call?
2. And when I receive the JWT, how do I parse it?

*

There are libraries like [redux-oidc](https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc) available, but doesn't look like its compatible in a react-native app (ran into a rabbit hole of errors).

[react-native-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-jwt) upon basic import on my react-native app, gives me an undefined split() error.

More info: I use redux-saga for middleware.

Hoping somebody can help me, even leads would be truly appreciated.

Comment: This question would be improved if you included what you have already tried to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working! Here's what I did.

1.) Set an Authorization Header with the base64 encoded client id and secret.

```
'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Base64.encode([client_id]:[client_secret])
```

I used a free Base64 library from the internet instead of relying on Javascript's `btoa()`.

2.) I did a POST request to **/connect/token** with the parameters `({ grant_type: 'client_credentials', ...})` and my scope. Made sure the data was sent via *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*

Got the token in the response!